# how to switch from light to dark theme in ipyvuetify?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, voila

I'm using ipyvuetify in a Jupyter Python environment to create an interactive dashboard for my end-user.

I would like to create an interactive toogle btn that switch `vuitify.theme.dark` from `True` to `False`

When I test this behaviour in voila with the following code :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

v.theme.dark = True

#validate the selected data 
v.Container(children=[
    v.Btn(color='primary', children=[
        v.Icon(left=True, children=[
            'mdi-square'
        ]),
        'Click me'
    ])
])
```

Only the surrounding of the `Btn` component have a dark background, the rest of the page keeps the voila light background.

A trick could be to add the `?voila-theme=dark` at the end of my url but then it's not dynamic anymore.

Is there a way to change both the `voila` and `ipyvuetify` theme ? or to force the `ipyvuetify` background to occupy all the screen ?

Comment: There is a related [open issue](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/464) on Voilà project, unfortunately without update since its opening in Nov 2019.

Comment: the issue has not been closed but the solution have been implemented: if you add "voila-theme=dark" as an option in your url then the theme is changed

Comment: Maybe this issue does not exist when using the [voila-vuetify](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-vuetify) template. Although it seems to be broken [recently](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila-vuetify/issues/43), so I could not try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick is to add an opaque **Overlay** component as background (`z-index=-1`) and change its color upon switching the ipyvuetify theme:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

dark_bg = '#121212'
light_bg = '#fff'

bg = v.Overlay(
    color=dark_bg if v.theme.dark==True else light_bg, 
    opacity=1, 
    style_='transition:unset', 
    z_index=-1
)

def bg_switch(widget, event, data):
    v.theme.dark = not v.theme.dark
    bg.color = dark_bg if v.theme.dark==True else light_bg

btn = v.Btn(children=[v.Icon(children=['mdi-theme-light-dark'])])
btn.on_event('click', bg_switch)

v.Container(children=[bg, btn])
```

No JS code required . The color definitions come from `vuetify.min.css` (v2.2.26 used by ipyvuetify 1.6.2): `#fff` in the light theme and `#121212` in the dark theme.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the **`body` background color**

With Voilà (default) lab template, the background surrounding the ipyvuetify application appears to be the HTML `body` background, so a workaround is to apply the background color of the ipyvuetify theme to the `body` background. Ipyvuetify-v.1.6.2 background colors are `#fff` in the light theme and `#121212` in the dark theme (from vuetify.min.css-v2.2.26).

The background color can be modified by adding an internal CSS in an HTML `<style>` element:

```py
dark_bg = '.jp-Notebook {background-color: #121212}'
light_bg = '.jp-Notebook {background-color: #fff}'

def bg_switch(widget, event, data):
    v.theme.dark = not v.theme.dark
    css.children = [dark_bg] if v.theme.dark==True else [light_bg]

btn = v.Btn(children=[v.Icon(children=['mdi-theme-light-dark'])])
btn.on_event('click',bg_switch)

css = v.Html(tag='style', children=[dark_bg] if v.theme.dark==True else [light_bg])

v.Container(children=[css,btn])
```

Another solution is to add an inline CSS by setting the JS HTML DOM Style backgroundColor property of `body`:

```py
class BtnTheme(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    dark = traitlets.Bool(v.theme.dark).tag(sync=True)
    template = traitlets.Unicode('''
    <v-btn icon @click="switchTheme">
      <v-icon>mdi-theme-light-dark</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <script> {created() {this.updateBackground()},
      methods: {
        switchTheme() {
          this.dark = !this.dark;
          this.updateBackground()
          },
        updateBackground() {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.dark ? '#121212' : '#fff'
        }
      }}
    </script>''').tag(sync=True)
    
btn = BtnTheme()
ipywidgets.jslink((btn, 'dark'), (v.theme, 'dark'))

v.Container(children=[btn])
```

In the above solutions, the theme button is initialised with the value of `v.theme.dark` which is `False` unless set to `True` earlier in the application code. In addition, the theme button can be initialised as the Voilà (lab template) theme:

1. by checking the query parameters:

```py
v.theme.dark = (os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING', '').find('dark') != -1)
```

2. or by checking at the beginning of the `created()` function the presence of [`theme-dark`](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/blob/9fa61a3e0ff7bb51c9aace7ec6cec0dd11b3a357/share/jupyter/voila/templates/lab/index.html.j2#L37) in the `body` classes:

```js
if (document.body.classList.contains('theme-dark')) {this.dark = true}
```

In case of unknown background colors, these two colors can be detected via two dummy elements, each styled with one of the two themes:

```py
class BtnTheme(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    dark = traitlets.Bool(v.theme.dark).tag(sync=True)
    v_dark_bg = traitlets.Unicode('').tag(sync=True)
    v_light_bg = traitlets.Unicode('').tag(sync=True)
    template = traitlets.Unicode('''
    <v-btn icon @click="switchTheme">
      <v-icon>mdi-theme-light-dark</v-icon>
      <div class="v-application theme--dark" id="v-dark-style"></div>
      <div class="v-application theme--light" id="v-light-style"></div>
    </v-btn>
    <script> {
      mounted() {
        this.v_dark_bg = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("v-dark-style")).backgroundColor
        this.v_light_bg = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("v-light-style")).backgroundColor
        if (document.body.classList.contains('theme-dark')) {this.dark = true}
        this.updateBackground()
        },
      methods: {
        switchTheme() {
          this.dark = !this.dark
          this.updateBackground()
          },
        updateBackground() {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.dark ? this.v_dark_bg : this.v_light_bg
        }
      }
    }
    </script>''').tag(sync=True)
```

Comment: I'm using ipyvuetify but try to stay as far away from the js code as possible. I t works perfectly thanks. Can you just explain me why you use `module.export` at the beginning of the script ?

Comment: I have updated the JS code to a simpler, more readable and efficient one. My previous answer based on changing the CSS background property of `.jp-Notebook` class to `--jp-inverse-layout-color` was also less aesthetic as the color is `#111111` whereas vuetify dark background color is `#121212`.

Comment: I have added a solution without JS code to change the body background color: by defining an internal `<style>` element (in the body) with an ipyvuetify `Html` component. The Voilà theme set by a query parameter in the URL can also be detected with Python.

Comment: @PierrickRambaud Actually, `module.exports` and anything between `<script>` and `{` in the `template` attribute is ignored by the parser in [`VueTemplateRenderer`](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvue/blob/master/js/src/VueTemplateRenderer.js#L318). I've removed it in the answer.